# How do I find the slope (rate) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do I find the slope (rate) in MATLAB?

For example, say I have a scatter plot:

```
Year = [2001 2002 2003 2004 2005];
Distance = [1.5 1.8 1.9 2.2 2.5];
scatter(Year, Distance)
hold on
pf = polyfit(Year,Distance,1);
f = polyval(pf,Year);
plot(Year,f)
```

And I can find R by:

```
[r,p] = corrcoef(Year,Distance)
```

I want to find the rate at which the distance increases per year, which I think is equivalent to the slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation of the slope in this case.  If you use [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) in that fashion, you are finding the slope and intercept of the regression line that best fits that distribution.  In this case, the slope would be the rate at which distance increases per year.  Without going into much detail, `polyfit` will determine the line of best fit that will minimize the sum of squared errors between the best fit line and your data points.  Therefore, this slope will give you the **best** rate at which distance is increasing per year, given your point distribution.

You can follow Chris A's approach in that you can find point-wise pairs of neighbouring points and compute a slope for each, then do an average, but doing `polyfit` will find the least squares regression line and in my opinion that's the way to go.

You can obtain the least squares, or best fit slope by extracting the first value of `pf` as you have already observed.  The second value will contain the intercept term of the regression line.

Good choice on using [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) to determine how good the fit is.  However, be careful and take the correlation coefficient with a grain of salt.  Some distributions may report a good correlation coefficient, but the actual best fit line will not look very good.  A classic example would be the [Anscombe quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet).  In this example, all distributions reported a correlation coefficient of 0.816, yet the variability in the data was quite different.  As a means of self-containment, this is what the data look like as well as the best fit line through each set of points.  You can see that the regression line is actually the same for all data sets, yet the point distribution is completely different:

[image]